# can you do a automatic HTML calendar?

Tags: html, css, calendar

I have done a calendar, a bit of the calendar is below. But now Im wondering if there is a way for the calendar to automatically update. Or do I need to write the code below for every month and every year or is there a method in eg PHP that helps you with that? I do not want to use bootstrap or a plugin.

```
  <table>
<lable>Januari 2018 </lable>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Su</th>
        <th scope="col">Mo</th>
        <th scope="col">Tu</th>
        <th scope="col">We</th>
        <th scope="col">Th</th>
        <th scope="col">Fr</th>
        <th scope="col">Sa</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>1<td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td> /*and so on for the reset of the month*/
```

Comment: HTML is not dynamic.  JavaScript and server side languages are dynamic.  It would be easier to just use existing and prebuilt calendars than to rewrite one.

Comment: @Makoto I was thinking about using javaScript. Are there functions in javaScript that enables automatic calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can build a dynamic calendar component.

Don't start a static approach like you have posted in your question.You have to learn the calendar/date api of your favourite language you want to use. It should be feasible in almost any language.

But it will be some effort and you have to get really into it. Maybe you rethink about using an already existing and tested component.

Comment: I was thinking about using javaScript. do you mean that javascript has a function that enables dynamic calendar?

Comment: You can build such a component on your own with "native" js or you find one of the many librarys for such a purpose.